# Below timecheck sql is failing in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was trying to check whether the input time lies between 2 times, if yes then return true else false.

was checking whether morning 1 am / 2 am / 3 am lies between prev day 10 pm to the current day 6 am. but for some reason, it is returning false.

**Below is SQL**

`SELECT '04:00:00'::TIME BETWEEN '22:00:00'::TIME AND '06:00:00'::TIME;`

Comment: Since 22 > 06, the between will never return true. You need to add day/overnight logic.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have two columns or parameters called `time1` and `time2`.  Then something like this:

```
(time1 <= time2 and '04:00:00'::time between time1 and time2) or
(time2 > time1 and '04:00:00'::time not between time1 and time2)
```

One small caveat:  Whether the boundary times match or not is different in the two conditions. I would suggest explicit logic (using `>`, `>=`, `<` or `<=`) just to be 100% on what happens.